# How can I get the screen back on ubuntu after it wakes up from sleep?

Tags: ubuntu, display

When I wake up my ubuntu from sleep, the screen has black and white lines.

I am on a presario x1000 laptop

Comment: Switch to another VT, then switch back.

Comment: @Ignacio I've been using linux since I was in 3rd grade and didn't know what CTRL+ALT+F1 did until last month.

Comment: Hi, this didn't fix it -- I close the lid and when I bring it back up, the screen is all messed up.